# Походження фразеологізму "підкласти свиню"

Tags: етимологія, фразеологізми

[Фразеологічний словник української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53409/361186.html)

> ***підклада́ти (підсува́ти, підставля́ти і т. ін.) / підкла́сти
> (підсу́нути, підста́вити і т. ін.) свиню́*** кому. Навмисне чи ненароком
> завдавати кому-небудь прикрощів, чинити підлість або діяти підступно
> проти когось.

Цікавить, як виник даний фразеологізм? Чому підкласти саме свиню, а не іншу тварину?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Існує декілька версій:

1. **Релігійна**. Відомо, що мусульманам не можна їсти свинину, тому якщо такій людині під час їжі подавали страву зі свинини, це ображало його релігійні почуття (тотбто хтось чинив йому підлість таким способом).
2. **Походження від [гри в свинки](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0_%D1%83_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8)**. За правилами цієї гри:

   > Кожен гравець у колі має перед собою ямку, в яку тикає кінцем палиці.
   >   Посередині кола трохи більша ямка, в яку той, що перебуває за колом,
   >   намагається загнати м'яча за допомогою палиці. Гравці, що стоять
   >   колом, намагаються не пустити м'яча в ямку посередині.
   >
   > Але, відбиваючи його палицею, кожен учасник повинен одразу ткнути її
   >   на своє місце, бо **той, хто «пасе свиню», заволодіє місцем, ставлячи у
   >   вільну ямку свою палицю. Гравець, чиєю ямкою заволоділи, починає
   >   «пасти свиню».**

   Тобто, в той момент, коли гравець заволодіває чужим місцем він "підкладає свиню" іншому гравцеві.
3. **Історична**. Існував такий бойовий порядок, який називався "свиня". Цитую [Вікіпеідію](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8#%D0%9A%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%84%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96):

   > У Західній Європі ( VIII - IX століття) головне значення в боях, з
   >   причини відсутності сильної піхоти, набула лицарська кіннота. Озброєні
   >   важкими списоми і мечами, закуті в броню лицарі (але ще без коней),
   >   атакували противника, шикуючись у лінію або клином. Улюбленою формою
   >   бойового порядку лицарського війська був усічений клин («**свиня**»),
   >   передні ряди якого становили добірні лицарі, що рухалася за головним
   >   клином піхота і прикривалася з флангів і тилу 2-3 шеренгами важких
   >   вершників. Піхота довершувала розгром супротивника, подавленого ударом
   >   щільної маси лицарів.

   Про цей бойовий порядок можна прочитати і в роботі А. Н. Нестеренко "[Современные трактовки боевого порядка рыцарской кавалерии Средневековья](http://history.milportal.ru/sovremennye-traktovki-boevogo-poryadka-rycarskoj-kavalerii-srednevekovya/)" і в СУМі (посилання у 4-ій версії). Такий вид наступу вважався досить грізним та завдавав противнику багато "прикрощів".
4. **Картярська гра**. В СУМі пише, що "[свиня](http://sum.in.ua/s/svynja)" має ще й значення "рід картярської гри". І тут же, знизу, дається фразеологізм "Підкладати (підкласти, підсувати, підсунути, підставляти, підставити і т. ін.) свиню". Також на [офіційному сайті української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/leksika/pokhodzhennja_frazeologizmiv/5-1-0-74) пише, що цей фразеологізм походить від картярської гри. На жаль, сам я в таку гру ніколи не гра та інформації про неї мені знайти не вдалося.
5. **Книжна**. За цією версією фразеологізм походить з книги [Ф. Рабле «Гаргантюа й Пантагрюель»](https://www.ukrlib.com.ua/world/printit.php?tid=3979&page=87), а саме:

   > Тоді, на брата Жановий розказ, теслі змайстрували великанську Льоху і
   >   поставили її на судно з кухлем. Склепали цю свиню і справді замашно:
   >   важкі гармати, поставлені на неї кружкома, плювалися камінними ядрами
   >   і чотиригранними крицевими списами, і нутрина її була така, що під її
   >   прикриттям могли битися понад двісті душ, і зроблена була Льоха за
   >   модлом Льохи Ларіольської, завдяки якій англійці за царювання юного
   >   короля французького Карла VI взяли Бержерак.
   >
   > Наводжу імена завзятих і хоробрих кухарів, залізлих у цю Льоху, ніби в
   >   троянського коня...

   Тобто герої зробили велику свиню, залізли туди і, у вирішальний момент битви, завдали противнику поразки.

Comment: «На жаль, сам я в таку гру ніколи не гра та інформації про неї мені знайти не вдалося» — я в дитинстві грав.

Comment: Ще є «забобонна» версія (можливо частково пов'язана з релігійною). Раніше (частково й зараз) люди (свідомо чи підсвідомо) вірили, що комусь можна наврочити, виконавши певні магічні дії. Серед таких магічних дій — насипати сіль і підкласти голову свині; з цього дехто виводить вирази «насолити» й «підкласти свиню».